# Multiple login challenges from PostgreSQL when using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am using PostGIS as my main data storage. I have two different geodatabases, one with internal data and one with various background maps. Both those connections are set up with stored user credentials, so I can connect to the databases without being asked for username and password. This works fine when adding a new layer to a project.

But, when opening a project using layers from one of those databases, I am asked for username and password for the database. "fe_sendauth, no password supplied" Why does this happen? Can I somehow fix the connection in an existing project?

Using QGIS 3.24.2 on Windows, connecting to PostgreSQL 14, but I am pretty sure I saw the same issue on older versions of both QGIS and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Does it work when you are adding your layer in the project ? Storing user&password doesn't not work when the connection has been edited. Layers in an existing project still doesn't store the user&password if the connection if the connection has been edited after.